# C++ code malfunctioning

Tags: c++

I wrote a basic linear search C++ code. Whenever I run this, the result I get is always the opposite of the expected result.
For instance, I want to search 4. In an array where it is present, it will say the number is not found, but upon searching an absent element, it will say the element is found at position 0.

Even after an hour or so of constantly looking at the code I have not found any solution.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

//scanning program
int linearsearch (int A[] , int z, int n, int srchElement) {
    for (int z = 0; z < n; z++) {
        if (A[z] == srchElement) {
            return z;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

//main program
int main () {
    int i, n, A[1000], z;
    //asking for size of array
    cout << "give size of the array needed to be scanned: ";
    cin >> n;
    cout << endl;
    if (n > 999) {
        cout << "invalid value";
        return -1;
    }
    //making sure of the size of the array
    cout << "enter " << n << " integers: ";
    //asking for the array
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cin >> A[i];
    }
    int srchElement, index;
    do {
        cout << endl << "enter element to search (-1 to exit ): ";
        //srchElement is defined here
        cin >> srchElement;
        if (srchElement == -1) break;
        index = linearsearch(A, n, srchElement, z);
        //calling thscanning function
        if (index == -1) {
            cout << srchElement << " not present" << endl;
        }
        //outputting the results of the scan
        else {
            cout << srchElement << " present " << index << endl;
        }
    } while (true);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: this code is absolutely impossible to read; you should format it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your search function correctly formatted:

```
int linearsearch (int A[] , int z, int n, int srchElement) 
{
    for (int z = 0; z < n; z++)
    {
        if(A[z] == srchElement)
            {return z;}
    } 
    return -1;
}
```

and here is how you call it:

```
index=linearsearch(A, n, srchElement, z);
```

- You pass a value `z` in with the call. It is unitialised and does nothing, in `main()` or in the function.
- You pass the arguments into the function in the wrong order. You are:

  - passing `n` (from `main()`) into the unused `z` value
  - searching for the uninitialised `z` (from `main()`)
  - passing in the element you are looking for as `n` (array size). (This will quite likely result in out of bounds error, e.g. if searching for `-1`)

Try this:

```
int linearsearch (int A[], int n, int srchElement) 
{
    for (int z = 0; z < n; z++)
    {
        if(A[z] == srchElement)
            {return z;}
    } 
    return -1;
}
```

and here is how you call it:

```
index=linearsearch(A, n, srchElement);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your parameters to `linearsearch` are not in the correct order - you are passing `n` into the unused `z` parameter. With your current function you should call it like:

```
index=linearsearch(A, 8675309, n, srchElement);
```

I recommend you get rid of `z` as a parameter, then you won't need to pass a value to it.

Also please note: Spaces and indentation do not make your program run slower, but they do make it a lot easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

The order of arguments in the function definition is not the same as in the function call.
It should be like (Line no 4):

```
int linearsearch (int A[] , int n, int srchElement, int z)
```

Answer (score 0):

You immediate problem: as The Dark spotted, this call:

```
index=linearsearch(A, n, srchElement, z);
```

doesn't match the declaration

```
int linearsearch (int A[] , int z, int n, int srchElement)
```

Function arguments in C++ are positional: just because the last call argument and the second declaration parameter are both *called* `z` doesn't mean anything.

Now, there are several local issues of style:

1. this kind of function is risky in the first place

   ```
   int linearsearch (int[],int,int,int)
   ```

   because it relies on you remembering the correct order for the last three integer parameters. If you *must* do this, you should be extra careful to give them all distinctive names, be very clear about which is which, and keep the order consistent across families of functions.

   It's better, where possible, to help the compiler help you out, by either giving the arguments distinct types (or enumerations, or whatever), or grouping them into a structure.

   For example, using a `std::vector<int>` instead of your array effectively groups `int A[]` and `int n` together in an object, so they can't get out of sync and `n` can't get confused with the other integers floating around
2. You shouldn't be passing `z` in the first place. You *immediately* hide it with a local `int z` in the loop, so it can't be doing anything. Remove it from both the declaration and the call. This simplification is sufficient to fix your bug.

---

Your secondary problem is that the code is *ugly*. It's poorly formatted and hard to read, and and that makes it more difficult to spot mistakes. Try to make your code simple and readable: there's less opportunity for things to go wrong, and its easier to see the problems when they occur.

Your tertiary problem is that the code is *bad*. Most of this can be done using standard library facilities (making your code simpler), which are themselves well-tested and generally have carefully-designed interfaces. Use them first, and replace if necessary.